# I want to use and update existing excel in my code, I am trying to access Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference but getting conflict error

Tags: c#, excel

I want to export some information to excel through my application hence I am trying to add Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference. I have added it and written using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; but still my code gives conflict error for office.cs file.

I have removed reference/using directives and tried removing office.cs file from below location to avoid conflicts but still getting the same error.
D:\Users\ASapkal\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Accumulators\Accumulators\Microsoft\

In directives I have used:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

This is in code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
```

This is the Error:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUnts.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try adding reference by the Project Tab, then Add Reference and in COM Tab select the  Microsoft Excel Object Library.

Comment: Tried but no luck,